# Where/when is the Jade Court first mentioned?

Tags: the-dresden-files

I have seen mentions of the Jade court of vampires pop up recently, even in my book for the Dresden Files RPG.  However, I have absolutely no recolelction of them being mentioned in the books.  Where did the Jade court first pop up, and what other meterial contains mentions of the Jade court?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Jade Court was referenced when we first met the Denarians, by Shiro.  He referenced having fought in duels against them before.  This was in *Death Masks*.

It has been speculated that they may be based on eastern 'chi' vampires.